# RPC full type specification from metadata

Tags: rpc, metadata, custom-types

Since [metadata v14 and `scale-info`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8615) were introduced, the runtime fully specifies all runtime interfaces and types. On the RPC side however the `rpc_methods` only returns the list of methods exposed, without any type details for them. This basically means that a mapping from these names to actual definitions are maintained in various SDKs.

There is also a version flag in this RPC response so it must mean it is somehow upgradable.

So my question is: are there plans and/or ongoing work to make these fully described with parameters and return types ala metadata-v14-for-rpcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a feature we have in mind, however at the moment there are no plans to implement it in the immediate future.

I have created an issue for it in Substrate: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11181, so keep an eye on that for any updates, and add any comments/suggestions you may have.

Comment: Thank you! Will subscribe to the issue above.

Answer (score 0):

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen/ might be exactly what you need to get started. Types are fully described, from the [getMetadata](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getmetadataat-blockhash-metadata) endpoint:

```
js API interface: api.rpc.state.getMetadata
jsonrpc: state_getMetadata
```

Note the value returned by the RPC is [SCALE encoded](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec), and needs to be decoded for you use.

[`subxt` is a good reference](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt) and for a simple CLI implementation decoding the output, [`subsee` is great too](https://github.com/ascjones/subsee)

Comment: Thank you. However the answer misses the question - I know how this applies to the runtime itself. However, the types for the params and the results are not specified for `rpc_methods` which is what this question relates to. Since we have the full type mapping now for the runtime, we should have it for RPC as well. A good example is the JS API which you linked - it has to do a manual mapping of all RPCs, e.g. this is for [api.rpc.chain.*](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/111540177f97b68ac8159069a0dbf5ad631c2b8c/packages/types/src/interfaces/chain/definitions.ts#L10-L86) in the JS API).